# Can't display "li" tag text for each checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have group of checkboxes, each of this checkbox associated to a "li" tag which contain a query result, I have also button, so I want when I check more than one checkbox and after that click on button, I want to display text of li tag for each selected checkobox. I have succeeded to display this data when I click one checkbox, but when I check more than one, it always display the last li text. From the code below,you will notice that "item" variable crash old text and display only the last "li" text, how can I keep both li text for each checkbox. I hope you undertsand my issue. Any help is appreciated.

Here is a snippet of code:

**php file:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


$('input[id^="DisplayCheckbox"]').on('click',function() 
{
            if($('input[id^="DisplayCheckbox"]:checked').length>=1)
  {
                
    parent = $(this).val();
    item = $(this).parents('#'parent).find("li.ListeGeom").text();
                alert(item);
                

            }else 
                alert(1);
        
});
 
    
});
        
</script>
```

external js file:

```js
$("#Afficher").click( function()
  {
      
            $.each($('input[id^="DisplayCheckbox"]:checked'), function(){            
                alert(item);
            });
            

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the accompanying HTML structure, there is going to be a bit of guesswork involved. But you're almost there I think, you just used the wrong version of .each. You want the `$(selector).each(...` syntax - this will iterate over the matched elements in jQuery instance, whereas the generic `$.each` will iterate over a conventional array or object.

```
$.('input[id^="DisplayCheckbox"]:checked').each(function(index, element){
      alert(element.id);
});
```

For more details, see https://api.jquery.com/each/

To find the li text, a bit more work is needed. Again I can't see the HTML, but the way you're finding them looks complex and brittle. You'd be better using classes or data attributes to associate them with each other, something like this:

Checkbox with value 1:

```
<input id="DisplayCheckbox" value="1" type="checkbox"/>
```

Associated li, which has a class including 1 at the end:

```
<li class="querytext1">Content</li>
```

Then it's trivial to find the associated text:

```
$.('input[id^="DisplayCheckbox"]:checked').each(function(index, element){
  alert($(".querytext" + element.value).text());
});
```

You can then do the same in your click event for each individual checkbox:

```
$('input[id^="DisplayCheckbox"]').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    alert($(".querytext" + this.value).text());
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being late, About html script I add it dynamicaly in php file like that: while ($row2 = pg_fetch_array($result2)) 
              {echo '<div id="' . $row['nom'] . '" class="col-sm-10"><li class="Liste">' . $row['nom'] . '</li><div class="checkbox chk"><label><input type="checkbox" name="id" id="DisplayCheckbox" value="' . $row['nom'] . '"></label></div>';
          // code           
echo '<li class="Liste" name="id" style="display:none;">' . $row1[0]. '</li></div><br/>';              
}

Comment: @nermiiine ok hopefully it will work. Please remember to upvote and/or mark as accepted answer if it helps you - thanks. For future reference please don't put your code into comments like that - it's unreadable, and others might not notice it. Instead please edit your question to include it. And in this case actually a sample of the generated HTML rather than the PHP would be more useful, then we know for definite the finished structure. :-)

Comment: Thank you fo this advices, but I want to be more clear, so my problemis I can't display associated li text for each checkbox when I click the button, but when I check each checkbox, the associated text is display, so the problem is how to pass this text correctly to button function. Do you understand my issue?

Comment: yes I do. My code above addresses both those issues, if you re-structure your HTML slightly as I've suggested. Have you tried it? What was the result? P.S. I have just changed it very slightly to be easier and closer to what you have got already (using the "value" property of the checkbox instead)

Comment: I change my coding logic so I keep only the checkbox function, I noticed no need to create other function. Thank you @ ADyson for your answers :)

Comment: @nermiiine no problem. If my answer has helped you please remember to upvote and/or mark as accepted answer - thanks :)